# Android: How to set ImageView of custom layout of Preference of PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Preference that I set its layout - in the XML file - to a custom layout created by me

```
   <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:key="help_preference_screen">
   <Preference android:key="help_preference" android:title="" android:layout="@layout/help_image_text" />
   </PreferenceScreen>
```

The custom layout consists of an ImageView & TextView.

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/help_frame_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/help_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/help_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/daj_help_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/help_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout> </FrameLayout>
```

During runtime I want to access / find the ImageView (help_image_view) to set its image, how can I do that?

```
public class helpactivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
 {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.userpreferences);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if there are unique layouts for the preferences and the sub view ids are unique (i.e. every `Preference` object has a different layout with different ImageView ids). Then you can access the ImageView normally by id. i.e:

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.help_image_view)).setImageResource(someResId);
```

Otherwise the Preferences API [isn't designed for such purposes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#SettingTypes) and doesn't provide a function for manipulating the source/image of an ImageView.